# postman and angukar cant send an image file to firebase storage in express js

Tags: javascript, angular, express, upload, multer

hi i have this issue where i keep getting 500 response error from postman and angualr when i try to tigger this method

```
exports.uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body)
    if (!req.file) {
      throw new Error('No file received in the request.');
    }

    const file = req.file;

    const fileName = `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`;
    const fileUpload = storage.bucket().file(`images/${fileName}`);

    const blobStream = fileUpload.createWriteStream({
      metadata: {
        contentType: file.mimetype,
      },
    });

    blobStream.on('error', (error) => {
      throw new Error(error);
    });

    blobStream.on('finish', async () => {
      const downloadURL = await fileUpload.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2, // 2 years from now
      });

      res.status(200).send({ imageUrl: downloadURL[0] });
    });

    blobStream.end(file.buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

and i calling this method like this
`app.post('/images', upload.single('file'), productController.uploadImage);`

i try to console.log(req.body) and the resposne was
[Object: null prototype] {}

> Error uploading image: Error: No file received in the request.

so i try to send the req with angular app and still the same error 500
here is an image from both postman and angualr
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo0Mn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OWio.png)

and here how i send the method using angular

```
 async uploadImage() {
    if (!this.selectedFile) {
      console.error('No file selected.');
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.selectedFile);
    console.log(this.selectedFile)
    console.log(formData)

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5001/rebarsalon/us-central1/api/images', formData);
      console.log('Image uploaded successfully:', response.data);
      // Handle the response as needed, e.g., display a success message or update the product with the image URL
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message to the user
    }
  }
```